# is it possible to force cp-sat to meet all the constraints for a feasible solution?

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

Dears
I read that CP-SAT for a feasible solution does not ensure that all constraints are met. Am I right? Is there a way to force it to met all of them even if the solution is "feasible"?
Does it provide the constrains met and not met?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong.
Every constraint must be met. And the solver checks all solutions produced to make sure they are valid.

I believe you are confused by the notion of enforced literals in constraints. This is the equivalent of index constraints in the MIP world.

Given a Boolean variable b, and a constraint (currently limited to bool_or, bool_and and linear_constraints), you can write

```
b => constraint
```

or

```
negation(b) => constraint
```

meaning that if the prefix is true, then the constraint must be satisfied.

Comment: Hi, probably I misunderstood that sentence: I got here: developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt_cp "On the other hand, for problems with highly non-convex feasible sets, the CP-SAT solver is often faster than the MIP solver. Such problems arise when the feasible set is defined by many constraints joined by "or," meaning that a point only needs to satisfy one of the constraints to be feasible."

Comment: or is another constraint (bool_or).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you read that? CP-approach means finding rather a good feasible solution than an optimal solutions, which obviously speeds up the computation.

The definition of a fesaible solution is: A set of values for the decision variables that satisfies all of the constraints in an optimization problem.

You can run an CP-SAT example and check, if a constraint is violated. But there should be not violation.

Edit: Or are we talking about relaxation?

Comment: Hi, probably I misunderstood that sentence: I got here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt_cp    "On the other hand, for problems with highly non-convex feasible sets, the CP-SAT solver is often faster than the MIP solver. Such problems arise when the feasible set is defined by many constraints joined by "or," meaning that a point only needs to satisfy one of the constraints to be feasible."

Comment: It is part of the model where you have alternative sub-models.  I build that task with that set of constraints OR with that other set of constraints.

Comment: @ Laurent Perron, I just noticed that you are directly involved in google OR tools. Could you give me some more ressources to learn them, besides the official documentation? Thanks in advance!